# Start media(audio+videos) from start in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

When anyone clicks on my **stop** button & then clicks on **play**, the Audio or Video plays from the start.

Here is the code that i am used to play the video/audio

```
_player.start();
_player.setLoopCount(-1);
```

Here is a code that i am used to stop the video/audio

```
_player.stop();
_player.setTimeBase(null);
```

But when i click on the stop, then play button, audio/video not play from start; it will resume the looping playback from where it was stopped.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setMediaTime(long now)` method to reset the time.

```
//Pause the player
_player.stop(); 

//Reset the time to 0
_player.setMediaTime(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a looong time researching this topic some years back. My conclusion was, that in order to re-start music from the start in a way that would work on all devices, would be to stop(), deallocate(), close() and null the Player object and then re-initialize it.

Theoretically you should use setMediaTime(), but that function is very very buggy on some devices, behaving very differently depending on device. Thus rendering the function useless.

More tips on music playback here: http://indiegamemusic.com/help.php?id=1